# how to make 2 foreign key combined as a unique key and cannot duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hrms_employee_leave` (
`employee_leave_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`leave_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`days` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Its will show the employee have how many leave,this is the data store in this table.

```
Employee_id = 25, 
leave_category_id = 2, 
days = 14

Employee_id = 25,
leave_category_id = 3,
days = 14
```

When I inner join the table the output is like

```
Employee Name = Foo,
Leave Category = Annual Leave,
days = 14
Foo has 14 days of Annual Leave.

Employee Name = Foo,
Leave Category = Medical Leave,
days = 14
Foo has 14 days of Medical Leave.
```

How to combined **employee_id** and **leave_category_id** became a unique key thats **cannot duplicate** to prevent user have insert more than one time

```
Employee_id = 25, 
leave_category_id = 2, 
days = 14

Employee_id = 25,
leave_category_id = 3,
days = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to add a multi column unique index. E.g. you can do it as part of the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hrms_employee_leave` (
`employee_leave_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`leave_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `uniqueindex_1` UNIQUE (`employee_leave_id`, `leave_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This way no `emloyee_leave_id` and `leave_category_id` **combination** can repeat. Also, neither of these can be NULL. Both if these columns can be a foreign key at the same time.

See example where those two columns are both foreign keys and a composite unique index: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4dfc

Comment: Hi,thanks your replay, but what i want is **employee_id + leave_category_id** combination and **cannot repeat**

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote and meant. Note the word "no" near the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Hi, if I had follow what you write to create my table, but another employee cannot take the same leave_category_id, `employee_leave_id is auto increament number`

Comment: Yes it can. See example with two different employees taking the same leave_category_id http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b6cc/1

Comment: What cannot be the same (cannot repeat) is **for a given employee_leave_id to have more than one row with the same leave_cateogry_id**.

Comment: Hi, i had tried but seem the same employee id still can take the same leave_category_id
[Image](http://imgur.com/GKB1691)

Comment: Its work when I changed   `CONSTRAINT uniqueindex_1 UNIQUE (employee_leave_id, leave_category_id)` to  `CONSTRAINT uniqueindex_1 UNIQUE (employee_id, leave_category_id)`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread it in the question. Throughout this answer I refer to 'employee_leave_id' instead of 'employee_id' so yes, replacing it should give the correct behaviour.